# how to devide a string into two halfs and convert each half into integer?

Tags: c

i get a string "hours" like this xx-yy , when this string resemble time for me , xx is a number betwen 0 ans 24 so is yy and xxshoul be smaller from yy .. i want to write a function that devides this string to two halfs xx and yy and i want to convert them to integers and check them .. this is what i wrote so far :
the function stops when it gets to strtok ! any ideas why ? thanks.
UPDATE: i get this error : No source available for "strtok()" .
input example hours=23:17 ..

```
bool working_hrsIsValid(char* hours){
    if (hours==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    if(strlen(hours!=6){
        return false;
    }

    char* ret=NULL;
    ret=strchr(hours,'-');
    if (ret==NULL){
            return false;
        }
    char s[2] = "-";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(hours, s);
    char* SRT_OPEN_HRS=token;
    token = strtok(hours, s);
    char* SRT_CLOSE_HRS=token;
    int openH=stringtoNum(SRT_OPEN_HRS);
    int closeH=stringtoNum(SRT_CLOSE_HRS);
    if (openH<0 || openH>24 || closeH<0 || closeH>24){
        return false;
    }
    if(closeH<openH){
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: There's a simpler way of not reinventing the wheel, its called `atoi`.

Comment: [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) comes to mind.

Comment: does `token = strtok(hours, s);char* SRT_OPEN_HRS=token;token = strtok(hours, s)` really work? shouldn't the second call be `token=strtok(NULL,s)`?

Comment: @t0mm13b: That wheel is a bit worn out. `strtoi` etc. are better, as they provide error handling and reading more than one value.

Comment: it stops in the strtok function

Comment: And your **specific** problem is … ? We are not a debugging service!

Comment: i wrote the probelm above

Comment: but isn't atoi for c++ ??? i am working with c

Comment: These guys here are asking what do you mean by "the function stops" do you get an error , an exitcode or something ?

Comment: What makes you think `atoi` is not available for `C`?

Comment: when the function gor for the first time to strtok the code stoped working suddenly and exit

Comment: @kasandra: Work through your C book. Most have a some example of either `atoi` or `strtoi`.

Comment: No source available for "strtok()" this is the mistake

Comment: hi olaf isn't atoi is used to c++?

Comment: "i wrote the probelm above" - err, no. You just dumped some code with little more than "it does not work". Read [ask].

Comment: yes i saied the problem is( No source available for "strtok()" ) i don't know what you want me to add i used debugger and this is what i got :/ i didn't find an answer so i asked here .

Comment: You should read a [man page for `strtok`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx) in detail, which shows a simple example usage. Also please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: ok but how to devide the string into two halfs xx and yy ?

Comment: Then you will need a more robust solution, such as the one in Stephen's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `sscanf` could be handy in this case. It avoids splitting the string into two parts "manually", like with `strtok`, and it might (intentionally) deal with leading spaces:

```
int main() {

    int openH=0;
    int closeH=0;

    const char* hour = "0-23";
    if (sscanf(hour, "%d-%d", &openH, &closeH) == 2) {
        printf("opening hours from %02d to %02d\n", openH, closeH);
    }
    else {
        printf("invalid format.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And just to clarify the issue with the "spaces": Format `"%d"` skips any leading spaces; Format `"%d-"` skips leading spaces, but requires a `-` following immediately the last digit. The following code adds some test cases to illustrate this:

```
int working_hrsIsValid(const char* hours) {

    int openH=0;
    int closeH=0;

    if ( (sscanf(hours, "%d-%d", &openH, &closeH) == 2)
       && openH >= 0 && openH < 24 && closeH >= 0 && closeH < 24) {

        //printf("opening hours from %02d to %02d\n", openH, closeH);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        //printf("invalid format.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void testOpenHoursFunction(const char *teststr[]) {
    while (*teststr) {
        printf("testing %s: %d\n", *teststr, working_hrsIsValid(*teststr));
        teststr++;
    }
}
int main() {

    const char* validOnes[] = { "   0- 23", "3- 18", "04-05", NULL };
    const char* invalidOnes[] = { "0 - 23", "-1- 23", "0-24", "0-", "-23", NULL };
    testOpenHoursFunction(validOnes);
    testOpenHoursFunction(invalidOnes);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
testing    0- 23: 1
testing 3- 18: 1
testing 04-05: 1
testing 0 - 23: 0
testing -1- 23: 0
testing 0-24: 0
testing 0-: 0
testing -23: 0
```

Comment: IIRC, `scanf` will skip spaces. It might not be suitable to allow spaces in a time/date format.

Comment: @Olaf: right; could be a bug, could be a feature. Hope it helps the OP anyway.

Comment: Hi guys, may I ask what spaces will be skipped by this code ? he is using `sscanf` not `scanf` and the hour format is given from the beginning. Thanks

Comment: You can see from the above code what you need to do. Now you can put the above into whatever function you want. Best of luck.

Comment: @CioacaRadu the answer uses `sscanf` instead of `scanf` because it simpilfies the problem by providing the input already coded into a string. The `Xscanf` family of  functions all behave broadly in the same way.

Comment: ...and @kasandra please note that you cannot use `strtok` on a string literal that is defined in this way.